Did Micro-USB have protection against "loops"?
I have an older USB power brick from a reputable, well-known company (i.e., not rock-bottom re-branded cheapest-as-possible). It has a female USB-A connector as output, and a female micro-USB connector to recharge the brick.
What I always wondered and never dared to try out, the obvious failure here would be to simply use a standard USB-A-to-USB-micro cable and create a loop for the device itself, connecting both of its ports.
Obviously you will not be able to accurately predict what my particular brick would do - but what would be the expected result for a well-designed product be, if it corresponds to best practices and the USB standard? I am aware that with USB-C, there is some negotiation going on before power is transmitted, so the ports should never be fully "live" anyways. Has the same been true for micro-USB?
To put it another way: Would an electronics engineer have to think long and hard how to solve this problem, or is it kind of trivial and "hard to get wrong"?

The USB-C "negotiation" you refer to is for Power Delivery / Quick Charge. 5 V is available with no negotiation (the CC [except to a pullup/pulldown] and data lines need not even be connected). So it's not true that "the ports should never be fully 'live'."

@TypeIA What you wrote is not true. Type-C receptacles are not allowed to output power until it detects a plugged in device with a role that requests power from supply. 5V will not be available until that point. And USB-PD is irrelevant, it will happen later, if it is even being used.

This question is not really about MicroUSB, it's about a hypothetical scenario of what would happen if you connected the output and input of your specific device together. We can't know what would happen, it depends on how your device is designed, there is nothing in MicroUSB specification that define this.

Also, I would not worry about a toddler plugging cables to a USB brick. The worrying part is that a toddler should not have had any access to a lithium battery pack to begin with, and it already happened. There are worse things that can happen, that someone plugging in a cable neatly between two ports of an USB brick. Things that damage the cells and they leak, explode or start a fire.

@justme, I mention in my question that I am aware that you cannot tell me what would happen (I specifically do not mention the exact brand and model for this reason). The core of the question is to figure out what a reasonable expectation for this would be, and whether it would pose a challenge for an engineer to design the brick in a way that would not behave catastrophically. I am very sure that experienced engineers can predict this with some probability. I have removed the toddler sentence, as jokes in questions probably do not add value.

@Justme Yes, I know all that. But a purely passive UFP will see 5 volts on VBUS. If you call a passive pulldown "negotiation" then that explains the confusion.

@TypeIA The role is negotiated with resistors, yes. The DFP (host/PC) receptacle does not output VBUS until it sees a connection to a UFP receptacle device that signals with resistors that VBUS is needed. Or it sees an active cable that requires VCONN.

Consumer electricity and electronics are generally built around the principle that if some connectors fit, they are safe to be plugged, and if the connection at all makes sense, they should work.
The most probable result of your experiment to try to charge the battery pack from itself would be slow self-discharge.
It will try to power itself. Most of these will turn off their outputs when powered from the input, so it will power itself off and then repeat the cycle.
Or it will cycle some power over its input and output circuits, losing some energy in the process.
Nothing of particular danger.

Pre-Type-C USB had two kinds of all connectors specifically to physically prevent invalid combinations. Type A was for the host-side, type B for the device side.
As long as nobody makes an A-to-A male-to-male cable, there's no way to fry one host (which also equals a power source in the pre-C world) by connecting it to another. (You will actually find such "suicide cords" on the market, but they aren't in anyway conforming to the standard and are a recipe for disaster.)
Your power brick has an A which behaves like a host and a micro-B which behaves like a device, so the two subsystems should work correctly when connected together (even with an intermediate hub or so).

This does not respond to OPs issues though, because he's talking about a device that has both upstream and downstream connectors. There's no problem connecting those ports together with a compliant A->µB cable.

USB has nothing to do with what you're asking, actually.
The USB type-A port (which may be mini-A or micro-A) provides 5 V power. That is typically (but not necessarily) true at all times while the device with the USB connector is powered on. The USB type-B port (which may be mini-B or micro-B) requires 5 V power be provided to it.
What, specifically, the device with the type-B port does with that power is up to the device; your power brick might try to charge its battery with it, or it might just do nothing. Sufficiently smart power bricks would probably refuse to charge while powering something; I have one that behaves like this. Others may stop outputting power while charging. Some very fancy ones could theoretically check if they're plugged into themselves and stop charging on that condition, but still allow you to charge them from something else while powering a third device, though I've never encountered one that does this (full functionality would require mapping the whole chain of devices plugged into it to ensure there's no loop, which gets complicated for little benefit).

True, I guess it's less an USB-focused than a more generic electrical question ("what happens if a battery-based charger charges itself").
